# How to bring updated collection of objects from appengine datastore with java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to get the updated object's list from my appengine web app, after i update an object.

if I look in the console, after the update operation i see the entity has the new values but when i ask for the list of objects it came to me with the old values as the update never took place

my update implementation is

```
 public void update( final T entity ){
        entityManager.merge( entity );
        entityManager.flush();
     }
```

and my retrieve list implementation is

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     @Transactional(readOnly = true)
     public List< T > findAll(){
        entityManager.flush();
        return entityManager.createQuery("select f from " + clazz.getName() + " as f").getResultList();
     }
```

Is there a problem in the update , the merge method or does datastore use any special cache that doesn't get refresh after this operation. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Have you read up on the eventual consistency documentation?

Answer (score 1):

As @dragonx noted in comment, this happens due to [eventual consistency of HRD](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency).

When an entity is updated, call to `put(..)` will return immediately when entity data is persisted, but before all associated indexes are built.

So, if you `put()` and then immediately `get()`, you will get consistent data, as `get()` does not rely on indexes to retrieve entity.

But, if you `put()` and then immediately `query()`, you might not get the updated data, as queries rely on indexes and index entries for inserted/updated entity are still being built.